# Terraform tag instance with instance az id in aws

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

could anyone help me in achieve tagging the instance with the instance availability zone id?

```
resource aws_instance this{
  ..
  tag {
    key = az
    Value = <this.Instance_az_id>
  }
}
```

example key az and Value us-east-2a

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show more of what you've tried? How are you placing the instances across availability zones?

Comment: You can get the AZ from the subnet that you specify.

Comment: Tagging in TF is via `tags { az = "${aws_subnet.this.availability_zone}" }` not as in the aws cli.

Comment: @Rama Krishna S please provide that input, if you want us to help.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the AZ from the subnet that you specify when defining the instance.

```
resource "aws_instance" "this" {
  subnet_id = "${aws_subnet.a.id}" 
  tags {
    az = "${aws_subnet.a.availability_zone}"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "a" {
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.main.id}"
  cidr_block = "10.0.1.0/24"
  availability_zone = "us-east-1a"
}
```

This works even if you don't define the AZ for the subnet (although this feels dangerous to run such setup..)